# i want to search for particular word with white space from statement Android

Tags: java, android

I want to search in list i get by firing an api.

I'm currently using indexof () to search but if i provide space after word it's searching but list is not properly updated.

example:
 I'e two record in list 1. Qtlist and Uses  2. android
 If i search for "and " then it has to show only 1. but it showing 1. & 2. both.

my function for this

```
  private ArrayList<BusinessDetails> GetSearchAdapterData(String searchKeyword) {

            final ArrayList<BusinessDetails> listData = new ArrayList<BusinessDetails>();
            String searchWith = "";
            Log.i("BusinessArray  ", "size is "
                    + sitesList.getBusinessArray().size());

            list.clear();

            if (sitesList.getBusinessArray() != null
                    && sitesList.getBusinessArray().size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getBusinessArray().size(); i++) {
                    // String searchWith = "";
                    searchWith += sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName;
                    Log.i("businessName ", "Bus_Name is "
                            + sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName
                            + " startwith " + startsWith);

                    if (searchWith.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        listData.add(sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i));
                    }

                }
                Log.i("List data is inside loop call", "Listdata" + listData.size());
            } else {
                Log.i("sitesList.getBusinessArray() is zero", "size Zero");
            }

            return listData;
        }
```

Changes I'e been done to my function are:

```
 private ArrayList<BusinessDetails> GetSearchAdapterData(String searchKeyword) {

            final ArrayList<BusinessDetails> listData = new ArrayList<BusinessDetails>();
            String searchWith = "";
            Log.i("BusinessArray  ", "size is "
                    + sitesList.getBusinessArray().size());


            if (sitesList.getBusinessArray() != null
                    && sitesList.getBusinessArray().size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getBusinessArray().size(); i++) {

                    searchWith += sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getBusinessArray().size(); i++) {
                    if (searchWith.matches(".*\\b" + searchKeyword + "\\b.*")) {
                        listData.add(sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i));
                        Log.i("Match Word fromList", "" + listData.get(i).busName);
                    }
                }
                    Log.i("List data is inside loop call", "Listdata" + listData.size());
            } else {
                Log.i("sitesList.getBusinessArray() is zero", "size Zero");
            }

            return listData;
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated so, please... help

Comment: the one who down vote they can surely do but after helping, Don't just down vote and leave if you know let us too.

Comment: In this edit first i get complete business name string then trying to compare with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly

```
sitesList.getBusinessArray().size() == 2  
sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(0).busName == "Qtlist and Uses"  
sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(1).busName == "android"
```

The first value of `searchWith` will be "Qtlist and Uses" and the second value of `searchWith` will be "Qtlist and Usesandroid" since you append the busName to `searchWith`.  Hence it is correct that both matches the indexof test.

Isn't it sufficient to omit the '+' and use

```
searchWith = sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I fire an API when i got three char in my edittextbox so, it returns me the array and then after that three words whatever i'm going to enter it's searching locally through this method. If you need I can add textwatchers code which i added to my edittextview but it's not the logic i added the method i use to search locally.

Comment: Why can't you (in your first version) remove searchWith and just replace it with sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName?  Can you indicate whether the results are correct then? If not, please try to explain why they are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string matches method and reg ex to match the whole word. Following is thew small example that u can use for your problem.

```
String[] ss={"Qtlist and Uses","android"};

        for(String s:ss){
            System.out.println("s is "+s+"  and it matches with "+s.matches(".*\\band\\b.*"));
        }
```

following is the out put of the program:

```
s is Qtlist and Uses  and it matches with true
s is android  and it matches with false
```

here `\b` has been used mark the word boundary. Hope it solves you issue.

EDIT 1: Try replacing following code:

```
if (searchWith.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKeyword.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        listData.add(sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i));
                    }
```

with

```
if (sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i).busName.matches(".*\\band\\b.*")){
     listData.add(sitesList.getBusinessArray().get(i));
}
```

Any word can be matched using the following regex

```
".*\\banyword\\b.*"
```

Comment: you tried by giving space after and i.e. "and " then it must show 1. one

Comment: I'm not getting same result i'm going to edit my post and adding new code.

Comment: your logic is really nice but Marc sol. works for me thanks for your time